# Bellman ford implementation does not work

Tags: c++, algorithm, bellman-ford

I tried to write bellman-ford algorithm and i see that its not working. The problem is, i (and anyone i asked) can not find the mistake, i think it must be something preety simple. At first it seem correct, cos for every example i used it it works good, for some of bigger ones it does not though. The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long tab[3001][3001];
long long t[3001];

int main ()
{
int v,e;
cin >> v >> e;
//number of vertices and edges
for (long long i=0;i<=v;i++)
{
    for (long long j=0;j<=v;j++)
    {
        tab[i][j]=20000000000;
    }
}
long long x,y,odl;
for (int i=0;i<e;i++)
{
    //unordered vertices
    cin >> x >> y >> odl;
    tab[x][y]=odl;
    tab[y][x]=odl;
}
for (long long i=1;i<=v;i++)
    tab[i][i]=0;



for (long long i=1;i<=v;i++)
    t[i]=tab[1][i];

bool q;

for (long long i=1;i<e;i++)
{
    q=false;
    for (long long j=1;j<=v;j++)
    {
        for (long long k=1;k<=v;k++)
        {
            if (t[j]>t[k]+tab[k][j])
            {
                t[j]=t[k]+tab[k][j];
                q=true;
            }
        }
    }
    //if there was no changes, break
    if (!q)
        break;
}
for (long long i=1;i<=v;i++)
{
    if (t[i]==20000000000)
        cout << -1<<endl;
    else
        cout << t[i]<<endl;

}
}
```

its supposed to cout shortest path from 1 to all vertices (including itself), or -1 if we cant reach it.

Comment: please include a precise description of how it does not work. "Does not work" is of zero use when trying to fix something

Comment: Bellman-Ford is working very well.  It is your implementation of Bellman-Ford that is not working.

Comment: @MikeNakis argh undone vote, because I felt like upvoting twice. It may be considered as nitpicking, but imho it is extremely important to distinguish between a broken algorithm and a broken implementation

Comment: Is it possible that the failing case has more than 3000 vertices?  Or a total distances above your 20...0 constant?

Answer (score 1):

One problem is with this line:

```
for (long long i=1;i<e;i++)
```

Bellman-Ford may need up to v-1 relaxations, not e-1.

Suppose e is equal to 1, i.e. you have 1 edge.  You program will not detect a route that uses that edge because this for loop will never enter the body.

Comment: ok, good point, it should be i=0, but i dont think it should be v there;

Comment: i mean while its only one edge it needs only one iteration to find the answers

Comment: @Junak Just open the next algorithm book and take a look at the Bellman-Ford algorithm. It uses N-1 iterations to relax the edges, where N is the number of vertices.

Comment: The greatest number of relaxations should be equal to the length of the longest path.  This is at most length v-1 (if a path uses all v vertices).  It is also at most length e (if a path uses all e edges).  So you can choose to iterate min(e,v-1) times if you want.  Normally e > v, so most implementations simply use v-1.